# Symfony 5 - how to get twig defined path in class

Tags: symfony, twig

In twig.yaml I have definded global path:

```
paths:
    '%kernel.project_dir%/public/assets/media': images
```

And now I would like to get this path (as a full real path) in one of my symfony class.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject `Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader` in your service and get the path through `$loader->getPaths('images')`. The container builder should already have the paths resolved for you - does that help?